# Extra lines and curves in guitar tablature?

Tags: guitar, sheet-music, tablature

What do these two things indicate in guitar tablature ?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]

This curve is called a **[tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(music))**. it means that you have to hold the note for both of the values indicated; a quarter and an eighth note.

[image]

This means that it's an [eighth note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_value). The way to indicate an eighth note, is a flag on top of the stem.

[image]

Basically it's tablature notation for this:

[image]